# Visual Studio 2015 html code completion is not working

Tags: html, visual-studio, code-completion

I'm really get used to do like `div.clearfix` and press tab and it automatically complete like `<div class="clearfix"></div>`
But suddenly it stopped working and that is really annoying. I did not install any other extension or something and I'm not using Resharper or anything like that tool.

I reset settings, I also hard reset vs but none of them is working. I also check options from tools and everything seems normal.

Do you know the way(s) to fix this?

**PS: I'm using VS Enterprise 2015 with Update 2**

Comment: This is more of a general question as a noob to web dev but is VS a good ide to use for building things that use html? Since it's not compiled it seems like overkill to try to use IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you describe sounds like the ZenCoding component to the [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) extension to Visual Studio.

I'm pretty certain that you don't get that type of code completion out of the box in VS 2015, so it seems likely you did have an extension or plugin, but it is no longer working.

Comment: You are definety right. I uninstalled because I can't use minify anymore with Web Essentials on VS2015. I installed again and fixed my problem. Thank you very much.